# Sending Email with Laravel swiftmailer (Connection could not be established)

Tags: laravel, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer, laravel-mail

When trying to send email using laravel swiftmailer & using smtp.gmail.com my php.ini ssl connection is open already but still get these errors
my .env file code

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=dg.shahneel21321@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=example123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl
```

Error # 1 (when using `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl`)
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tsl://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Unable to find the socket transport "tsl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Error # 2 (when using `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`)
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I also tried already give solution on stackoverflow
add this to mail.php

```
 'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
      'allow_self_signed' => true,
      'verify_peer' => false,
      'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
  ],
```

also adding the following lines to `_establishSocketConnection()` in

```
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
```

Please help!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your password admin's one in google account?

Comment: how can i set it on google